# Print rows with condition on field data

Tags: awk, sed

I have file with data

```
cell   input     out    type      fun            level
AI20   A1,A2      Z     comb    ((A1A2))           2
IA2    A1,A2,A3   Z     comb    ((!A1A2)A3)        3
XOR    A1,A2,B1   Z     comb    (((A1A2)B1)        3
IAD    A1,A2,A3   Z     comb    (!((A1A2)A3))      3
INV    I1         ZN    comb    (!I1)              1  
BUF  A1,A2,A3,B1  Z     comb    (!(((A1A2)A3)B1))  4
```

> From this data, I want to print rows whose `level field (6th column)` gives `sum 7` together.
>
> here to get `level sum` `7` we can select `AI2O` ,`BUF` ,`INV` rows giving level sum as `2`+`4`+`1`=`7`and print them
> `Or` can select `XOR`,`IAD`,`INV`giving sum `3`+`3`+`1`=`7` and print them. Any random selection of rows work but `level sum` needs to be `7`

Output can be as

```
cell   input     out    type      fun            level
AI20   A1,A2      Z     comb    ((A1A2))           2
INV    I1         ZN    comb    (!I1)              1  
BUF  A1,A2,A3,B1  Z     comb    (!(((A1A2)A3)B1))  4
```

Or output can also be

```
cell   input     out    type      fun            level
XOR    A1,A2,B1   Z     comb    (((A1A2)B1)        3
IAD    A1,A2,A3   Z     comb    (!((A1A2)A3))      3
INV    I1         ZN    comb    (!I1)              1
```

I tried it using awk

```
awk '{{ sum[i] += $6} for (i=1;i<8;i++) print $0}' file
```

But this is printing each row 7 times not the desired output.

Part 2. Prblm continue to part 1.

file2 with data

```
cell   input  out  type   fun  level
CLK    C       Z    seq   Cq   1      
DFk    C,Cp    Q    seq   IQ   1
DFR    D,C     Qn   seq   IN   1
SKN    SE,Q    Qp   seq   Iq   1
```

Output to get for part2

```
cell   input     out    type      fun            level
AI20   A1,A2      Z     comb    ((A1A2))           2
INV    I1         ZN    comb    (!I1)              1  
BUF  A1,A2,A3,B1  Z     comb    (!(((A1A2)A3)B1))  4
CLK    C          Z     seq      Cq                1
XOR    A1,A2,B1   Z     comb    (((A1A2)B1)        3
IAD    A1,A2,A3   Z     comb    (!((A1A2)A3))      3
INV    I1         ZN    comb    (!I1)              1
DFk    C,Cp       Q     seq      IQ                1
IA2    A1,A2,A3   Z     comb    ((!A1A2)A3)        3
XOR    A1,A2,B1   Z     comb    (((A1A2)B1)        3
INV    I1         ZN    comb    (!I1)              1
```

output for part2 is that when we get level sum as 7 for file1, insert first line from file2 after it. And again check for condition for level sum 7 and if true insert second line from file2. Then again check for level sum as 7. If true insert 3rd line from file2.  This is done for execution 3 times.

Comment: you awk command is running 7 times for each line because of the for loop,which is causing each line to be printed 7 times

Comment: Then how can I check condition for getting rows with total sum as 7?

Comment: How long is your level column? Do you want ALL the combinations that give sum 7? And do you want combinations of any length (eg 1-1-1-1-1-1-1 will be selected too?)

Comment: @IoaTzimas.. The level column is very larger around 600 rows with level column having repeated nos 1, 2,3,4,5..  Combination can be of any length. Your eg can also be used. I want only a single combination that gives sum 7 to be displayed. But yes every time the selection should be random When I execute the code.

Comment: Ok, and what do you want as output? All possible combinations of rows? With 600 rows, you may probably have a huge issue with efficiency. For example 200 rows produce more than one million of combinations of 3 items

Comment: in output I want to display cell,input,output,type,func,level table for rows whose column level sum gives 7. You can see possible outputs which I can get if sum I need is 7 in the question.

Comment: @IoaTzimas... i want  to display ```only one combination giving sum 7 at a time when I execute```.But for each execution the selection should be random.

Comment: Do you want ALL possible combinations of rows? With 600 rows, you may probably have a huge issue with efficiency. For example 200 rows produce more than one million of combinations of 3 items. If yes I would suggest you provide a link with your entire dataset. Maybe there are some ways to reduce the calculation time.

Comment: @IoaTzimas .. can you help me with this smaller data in question. Later I will modify code for larger file. For larger file I may need bigger sum in hundreds so combination will be less. Since in the given question data is small so I took sum also small I.e  7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an awk solution for this job:

```sh
cat rnd.awk
function rnd(max) {        # generate a randon number between 2 and max
   return int(rand()*max-1)+2
}
BEGIN {
   srand()                 # seed random generation
}
NR == 1 {                  # for header row
   print                   # print header record
   next
}
{
   rec[NR] = $0            # save each record in rec array with NR as key 
   num[NR] = $NF           # save last column in num array with NR as key
}
END {
   while(1) {              # infinite loop
      r = rnd(NR)          # generate a randomm number between 2 and NR
      if (!seen[r]++)      # populate seen array with this random number
         s += num[r]       # get aggregate sum from num array

      if (s == 7)          # if sum is 7 then break the loop
         break
      else if (s > 7) {    # if sum > 7 then restart the loop
         delete seen
         s = 0
         continue
      }
   }
   for (j in seen)         # for each val in seen print rec array
      print rec[j]
}
```

use it as:

```sh
awk -f rnd.awk file
```

```
cell   input     out    type      fun            level
AI20   A1,A2      Z     comb    ((A1A2))           2
INV    I1         ZN    comb    (!I1)              1
BUF  A1,A2,A3,B1  Z     comb    (!(((A1A2)A3)B1))  4
```

and again:

```sh
awk -f rnd.awk file
```

```
cell   input     out    type      fun            level
IA2    A1,A2,A3   Z     comb    ((!A1A2)A3)        3
XOR    A1,A2,B1   Z     comb    (((A1A2)B1)        3
INV    I1         ZN    comb    (!I1)              1
```

Comment: This is GREAT answer, I was looking for how permutations and combinations will be created on this one, cheers for sharing nice solution here, thank you sir.

Comment: Thanks @RavinderSingh13. This algorithm is based on random number generation which is generated between 2 and row_count-1 (as there is a header row). We keep adding `$NF` for a random row in `s` and as long as `s==7` we bail out and print those records.

Comment: Yes sir, it was great. I have some more questions in this. Should I ask it separately.

Comment: i will answer your  queries here but if it is for a different problem then you can post a new question as well

Comment: Sir, I have added to above question, part2 which has file2 with given data. In this I want to add ```CLK line from file2``` after we get level sum as 7. And repeat this process 3 times for file1. Desired output is also shown above. In your above code we can change```while loop to for loop with i <= 3 condition``` but how can I add line from file2 after line ```if (s==7)``` is true.

Comment: yes sir, please refer to part2 : Prblm continue to part 1. Section in above question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224200/discussion-between-anubhava-and-neha-choudhary).

Answer (score 2):

There are two places where efficiency is important in this problem:

1. Generation of all the possible combinations;
2. Retrieving of the right line once the combination is known.

The first issue is extremely dependent on the number of possible values that you have as "level". If you have "hundreds" of different values the number of possible combinations giving you a requested sums is going to be very very large and thus, you want to optimize that part of the algorithm.

The second part is dependent on the number of lines you have in the file. To address this problem I would create an hash table where keys are the value of the "level" and values are arrays of string with each string being one of your line.
Once you have a given combination, you can generate (virtually infinite) combinations almost instantaneously with the following steps:

1. retrieve the array of strings associated to each of the `level` value present in the combination;
2. from each array of strings retrieve a random string;
   3 repeat the process to get as many combinations of string as you want associated with a given combination of `level` numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The following function will return a random combination of rows where the sum of level column is equal with the target (currently 7 as per your question). It can work with any dataframe (as long as there is a numerical column 'level') and any target:

```
import random

def get_one(df, target):    
    indices=[]
    values=[]
    while sum(values)<target:
        dftemp=df[(df['level']<=target-sum(values)) & (df['level']>0)]
        ind1=random.choice([i for i in set(dftemp.index)-set(indices)])
        indices.append(ind1)
        values.append(df.loc[ind1, 'level'])
    return df.loc[indices, :]
```

To get a result, just run the function using df and your target as parameteres:

```
>>>get_one(df, 7)

cell   input     out    type      fun            level
AI20   A1,A2      Z     comb    ((A1A2))           2
INV    I1         ZN    comb    (!I1)              1  
BUF  A1,A2,A3,B1  Z     comb    (!(((A1A2)A3)B1))  4
```

If you want other total, you can change the parameter, for example:

```
>>>get_one(df, 10)
>>>get_one(df, 15)
```

etc

Comment: ```yourdf``` here is ```file name containing data```??

Comment: Are there any 0's in your level column? If yes, let me know so that i will adjust the code (ignore this comment, i updated the code so that it will work with zeros too)

Comment: df is your original dataframe

Comment: @IoaTzimas how do you make sure that the total is 7? (not familiar with pandas)

Comment: @RiccardoPetraglia while condition checks for this, and it will stop when total gets exactly 7

Comment: @IoaTzimas oh... because of this `(df['level']<=target-sum(values))` the sum cannot be higher than 7... right?

Comment: @RiccardoPetraglia Exactly! Possible new values of 'level' column cannot give a total larger than target

Comment: If sum i want is other than 7 , then will this not work. In the above code where I am defining sum 7 as you mentioned it is in target????@IoaTzimas

Comment: No, it works for any total you want, not only 7. I added some description, how to run the code with other totals

Comment: @IoaTzimas I am writing this code inside my script. if my ```input data is in file1``` so here in your code, at start of code, I need to give ```df = open("file1","r")``` ??  And how can I display the final output in a output file???

Comment: The input (df) and output of my function get_one() are dataframes. To create a dataframe from a file or save a dataframe to a file, you can use various ways. One of the best solution is pandas with pd.read_csv('file1') to read your file1 and df.to_csv('newfile.csv') to write your new dataframe to a file.

Comment: @IoaTzimas..Thanks for your ans, but i am using python from system ```/bin/python``` so I am getting error ```No module named pandas```.